# Cheerio - Unresolved function or method load()

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to do a discord bot that gets images with Cheerio

I installed the library with `npm install cheerio --save`

And add the following code:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);
```

the problem is that WebStorm says that the function .load is not resolved

I tried to see inside the library and didn't find any load method. And if I execute the code that way I receive an empty object in `$`

the entire code:

```
const $ = cheerio.load(responseBody); 

const links = $(".image a.link");
const urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));
console.log(urls);
```

the console shows an empty array `{}`

Comment: have you tried reinstalling the package, or maybe enabling nodejs support for the ide? there does not seem to be any issue with the code itself

Comment: i have tried to go back some vesions and i enabled nodejs, but seems not the case

Comment: let me ask you one thing, does the code execute correctly or is this just an editor issue? what you wrote in your posts suggest that it's the latter

Comment: The code execute normaly but when i continue the code nothing happens, i will add the role code on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that the problem isn't in the function .load, but after that the dopfile website are not sending image withou do a captcha and thats why i was getting a empty array, ty everbody and sry